# Test the app in real iPhone, but it keeps running the old version app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing

I have tested my app on the real iPhone for a while and everything has been working perfectly fine. Then an accident happened -- during the development, I disconnected my iPhone to do something else. When I came back and resume the work, the test just doesn't work properly any more. I have updated the app, but in each test, it keeps running the old version.

What's even more weird is: it's not even running the version right before the unplug accident. It's actually running a version before that.

I have tried a few things, such as disconnect and restart iTunes/XCode/iPhone etc, but it still runs the same version.

I opened the Organiser, it does give the message of "**Xcode cannot find the software image to install this version**", BUT what doesn't make sense is -- it worked perfectly just half an hour ago!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean Your project build then restart your device and now instal the app into original device,

Comment: How do I clean my project build? Thank you!

Comment: cmd+k to clean your project
if not work then delete the build from the project then your problem may be solve

Comment: I kept trying a few things, tossing and turning... and somehow it just got working again! Haha... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

delete your app from your device and run it again